# Как осуществить проверку наличия первичного ключа в модели Pydantic 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic-2.x

У меня есть схема написанная на Pydantic 2 и используемая для проверки присылаемых полей:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CommandSchema(BaseModel):
    product: int
    title: str
```

Каким образом можно проверить, что присылаемое поле product является ключем из модели Product?
По идее предполагается использование примерно следующего кода:

```
class CommandSchema(BaseModel):
   product: int
   title: str

    @validator('product')
    def validate_product_field(cls, value):
        session = Session(bind=engine)
        if session.query(Product).filter(Product.id == value).first():
            return value
       
        raise ValueError(f"Field '{value}' already not exists in the database.")
```

Но у меня используется асинхронное подключение к БД. Соответственно, я не могу выполнить await код, наподобии такого:

```
async with engine.begin() as conn:
            async_session = sessionmaker(conn, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
            async with async_session() as session:
                if await session.execute(Product.select().where(Product.id == value)):
                    return value
                    
            raise ValueError(f"Field '{value}' already not exists in the database.")
```

так как запускаться он будет внутри метода, который не является асинхронным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй использовать [pydantic-async-validation](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-async-validation/).

Установка

```
pip install pydantic-async-validation
```

Пример использования

```
import pydantic
from pydantic_async_validation import async_field_validator, AsyncValidationModelMixin


class SomethingModel(AsyncValidationModelMixin, pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str

    @async_field_validator('name')
    async def validate_name(self, value: str) -> None:
        if value == "invalid":
            raise ValueError("Invalid name")


valid_instance = SomethingModel(name="valid")
await valid_instance.model_async_validate()

invalid_instance = SomethingModel(name="invalid")
await invalid_instance.model_async_validate()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)